# Cannot run conda in terminal on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, conda

I have problems running the `conda` command in a terminal window on MacOS. I know I am not alone, because I have researched many answers to this question, yet still cannot solve it. Here is what I did specifically.

I downloaded Anaconda3 2019.10 for macOS (Python 3.7 version, 64-Bit Graphical Installer (654 MB)) from here: https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/ and installed it using all default settings.

I opened a terminal window on my mac to run `conda --version`. Then it says:
`conda: Command not found.`

I have read various posts saying that you need to modify your `~/.bash_profile`, so I `open ~/.bash_profile` and it looks like this:

```
 # added by Anaconda3 2019.10 installer
 # >>> conda init >>>
 # !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
 __conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
 if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
     \eval "$__conda_setup"
 else
     if [ -f "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
         . "/opt/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
         CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
     else
         \export PATH="/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
     fi
 fi
 unset __conda_setup
 # <<< conda init <<<
```

Then I added the line:

```
 export PATH=/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

This did not solve it. When I instead used any of the lines:

```
 export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
 export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/anaconda3/bin
 export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/opt/anaconda3/bin
```

this did not solve it either.

In a terminal window, I also tried to run the `conda` command in various folders/directories, especially `/anaconda3` sub-folders, but no luck either.

Every time I open terminal and try to run `conda --version` to see if it works, it says: `conda: Command not found.`  I don't know what to do anymore. Could anyone help, please?

Comment: Did you run `source ~/.bash_profile` or `. ~/.bash_profile` after editing the profile file? What happens if you run `/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda --version` in your terminal? Have you restarted your machine since you installed?

Comment: I did not run ```source ~/.bash_profile``` or ```. ~/.bash_profile``` after editing the profile file.  I just exited the terminal window and opened a new one.  However, I tried running ```/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda --version``` just now, as you suggested and amazingly, that worked!  I can't believe it after everything I tried! Thank you so much! Very grateful!

Comment: So all the path thing does is tell your terminal where to look for executables. This  `export PATH=/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH` command is just saying "prepend my path list with `/opt/anaconda3/bin` (the `:` is the list separator for your path). That way, when you type `conda`, it looks through all folders in your path (and the `conda` executable is in the mentioned folder). You can type `echo $PATH` in your terminal and it will print out the current folders on your path. If you reboot your machine it'll have the defaults and whatever you append in `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: The suggestion I made earlier was to run the executable by specifying the full path---this should always work, unless the executable is broken. Your path is probably just screwed up. You can try cleaning it by just resetting it. You can `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` or whatever default locations you want, and then run `source ~/.bash_profile` to have your profile prepend the anaconda path. Echo it, make sure it looks right, and try running `conda` again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since macOS 10.15, the default shell is not bash, but zsh. It might explain why modifying your `.bashrc` did not help.

According to the [FAQ](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/#installing-anaconda), what you should do in case `conda` was not set up correctly is **not** to modify the `PATH` variable manually, but instead try to run

```
source <path to conda>/bin/activate
```

This will activate the base environment and make sure that `conda` is set up correctly for the **current** session. This can be followed by:

```
conda init
```

to ensure that `conda` is added to the correct files for the current terminal, which might be `zsh` in your case and not `bash`

Answer (score 1):

You may also access the anaconda-navigator path/location through your MAC Finder.

Find the application in your finder, and right click to select the "New Terminal at Folder" option, and the terminal should open to directly use conda.